# DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist error

Tags: java, selenium, electron, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to test my electron app on chromedriver but i keep getting the error "org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.43.600210 (68dcf5eebde37173d4027fa8635e332711d2874a),platform=Windows NT 10.0.18363 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)"

My setup is:

```
public class SetUp extends TestRail {



private static ChromeDriver browser;
public static String urlHost;
public static String testEnv;
public static PageConfig pageConfig;




@Before
public static WebDriver initialBrowser() {


    String projectLocation = System.getProperty("user.dir");
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", projectLocation + "/chromedriver.exe");

    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addArguments("start-maximized"); // open Browser in maximized mode
    options.addArguments("disable-infobars"); // disabling infobars
    options.addArguments("--disable-extensions"); // disabling extensions
    options.addArguments("--disable-gpu"); // applicable to windows os only
    options.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage"); // overcome limited resource problems
    options.addArguments("--no-sandbox"); // Bypass OS security model
    options.setBinary("C:/Electron.exe");
    options.setPageLoadStrategy(PageLoadStrategy.NORMAL);
    browser = new ChromeDriver(options);
    return browser;
}
```

The electron verison im using is 4.2.12 and chromedriver version 2.43.600210